# How can I make date increase with jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I have a jquery slider with a minimum value of 1 and maximum value of 41. when I drag the slider i want to be able show corresponding date based on the value of the slider displayed in the textbox. this is my slider code
/*slider2 begin */

```
$("#slider2").slider("value",1);
$("#slider2").slider({
    max:41,
    min:1,
     /*
    change:function(event,ui){
        $("input#days").val(ui.value)
    }
    */
    slide: function(event, ui) {   $("#days").val(ui.value) }
});

$("#days").val($("#slider2").slider("value"));

$("#days").change(function(event) {
  var data = $("#days").val();
  if (data.length > 0)
  {
     if (parseInt(data) >= 0 && parseInt(data) <= 41)
     {
         $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", data);
     }
     else
     {
        if (parseInt(data) < 1)
        {
            $("#days").val("1");
            $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
        }
        if (parseInt(data) > 41)
        {
            $("#days").val("41");
            $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "41");
        }
     }
  }
  else
  {
    $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
  } 
});
```

Comment: can you create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the same??

Comment: yeah but does creating jsfiddle help me sole the problem?

Comment: It helps us solve your problem :)

Comment: If you create it others can understand your problem easily!!

Comment: You have slider value 1 to 41, and want to set date in the textbox. I set up a basic jsfiddle,  edit it as your requirement http://jsfiddle.net/VXaCf/ , so we can help you.

Comment: I have created the jsfiddle as advised.

Comment: @YograjGupta am not displaying the date in the textbox. the numbers will increase on the textbox but i will create a div to display the date as the slider increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply add the number of days to the current date, you could use a function like this:

```
function addDaysToDate(days) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + (24 * days));
  return d;
}
```

You would just pass in the numeric days argument (which in the example would be the value from #days) and you would get back a date that many days in the future.

Comment: @jcern...please pardon my question as I am very new to jequery and javascript. did i pass in the numeric days argument correctly this way?  function addDaysToDate(days).$("#days").val() {
       var d = new Date();
       d.setHours(d.getHours() + (24 * days));
       return d;
      }

Comment: You'd probably want something like: addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())). I updated the fiddle to reflect a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq7xK/2/

Comment: thanks for your help @jcern I have implemented the code but i tried to make the #datediv display a default date that corresponds with the #days div but i get an invalid date this is the code i used:     
     $("#date").val($("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())))); also please how can i get rid of the timestamp as all i want is jus the first bit of the date that has the day,month,date and year

Comment: There was no default value on the input. This should work for you, it sets the default value on the input and formats the date: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq7xK/3/ -- There are no native javascript date formatting objects, so the function breaks the date up and formats it manually. For better control, there are plenty of third party libraries designed for that purpose, like: http://www.datejs.com/ or http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format